# How to get the Doctrine cascade persisting working?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, one-to-one, laminas-api-tools

I'm working on a ZF2/Apigility application using Doctrine `v2.4.2`.

The model structure looks like this: `an` `Asset` `has` `an` `Attachment` (so, it's a `1:1` relationship):

[image]

The problem is that I cannot persist an `Asset` with an embedded `Attachment` and get the error

> 23000, 1048, Column 'attachment_linkassetuuid' cannot be null

It seems that Doctrine tries to save the `Attachment` first, cannot find a value for the column `attachment_linkassetuuid`, sets it to `null`, and the foreign key constraint is broken.

**How to define the entities correctly and get the cascade persisting working?**

---

**`Asset`**

```
namespace MyDoctrineDataAccess\Model\Entity;
...
/**
 * Asset
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tbl_asset")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Asset
{
    /**
     * @var string @ORM\Column(name="asset_uuid", type="string", length=36, nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     * @var \MyDoctrineDataAccess\Model\Entity\Attachment
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="MyDoctrineDataAccess\Model\Entity\Attachment", mappedBy="asset", cascade={"remove", "persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $attachment;
    ...
}

/**
 * @param \MyDoctrineDataAccess\Model\Entity\Attachment $attachment
 */
public function setAttachment($attachment) {
    $this->attachment = $attachment;
    return $this;
}

/**
 * @return the $attachment
 */
public function getAttachment() {
    return $this->attachment;
}
```

**`Attachment`**

```
namespace MyDoctrineDataAccess\Model\Entity;
...
/**
 * Attachment
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="tbl_attachment", indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_attachment_uuid", columns={"attachment_linkassetuuid"})})
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Attachment
{
    /**
     *
     * @var string @ORM\Column(name="attachment_uuid", type="string", length=36, nullable=false)
     *      @ORM\Id
     */
    private $uuid;

    /**
     *
     * @var \MyDoctrineDataAccess\Model\Entity\Asset
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="\MyDoctrineDataAccess\Model\Entity\Asset", inversedBy="attachment", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="attachment_linkassetuuid", referencedColumnName="asset_uuid")
     */
    private $asset;
    ...
}

/**
 *
 * @param \MyDoctrineDataAccess\Model\Entity\Asset $asset
 */
public function setAsset($asset)
{
    $this->asset = $asset;
    return $this;
}

/**
 *
 * @return the $asset
 * 
 */
public function getAsset()
{
    return $this->asset;
}
```

**`AssetService`**

```
namespace MyApi\V1\Rest\Asset;
...
class AssetService implements ServiceManagerAwareInterface
{
    ...
    public function saveAssets($data)
    {
        $entityManager = $this->serviceManager->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        $assetRepository = $entityManager->getRepository('My\Model\Entity\Asset');
        $hydratorManager = $this->serviceManager->get('hydratormanager');
        $hydrator = $hydratorManager->get('My\\Model\\Entity\\Hydrator\\EntityHydrator');
        foreach ($data as $assetData) {
            $asset = new Asset();
            $hydrator->hydrate($assetData, $asset);
            $entityManager->persist($asset);
            $entityManager->flush();
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is your hydrator definitely working correctly, does it hydrate the `Asset` *and* the `Attachment`? Also, isn't the hydrated object returned from `hydrate`, unless you've customised it to be passed by reference? e.g. `$hydrated_object = $hydrator->hydrate($assetData, new Asset());`

Comment: Hello and thanks for your comment! I've just checked this. At the moment of persisting (`$entityManager->persist($asset);`) the `Asset` entity is built correctly and its property `attachment` is an `Attachment` entity object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `@JoinColumn` defaults `nullable` to `true` [according to the Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-joincolumn) I don't really understand the error. But I do see that in your `Attachment` entity `@table` definition you declare an index:

```
indexes={@ORM\Index(name="fk_attachment_uuid", columns={"attachment_linkassetuuid"})}
```

Try once to remove this, rebuild your database and check if it solves your issue. If not then leave a comment and I will have another look.

Check [the `OneToOne` example in the Doctrine documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional). Adding an `@index` like you do is not mentioned there. Doctrine will add the necessary indexes automatically to your relationship columns.

### UPDATE:

I think the problem might be that `Asset` is not the owning side of the relationship. Check the documentation [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/unitofwork-associations.html#important-concepts). Try to change your `setAttachment` method like this:

```
public function setAttachment($attachment) 
{
    $this->attachment = $attachment;
    $attachment->setAsset($this);
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Well, sure, that way I can avoid the error. But what you're actually recommending is removing the foreign key constraint (since it's necessary for removing this index). The next step would be then to make the column `attachment_linkassetuuid`. But it will only result in an inconsistent database with `attachment.attachment_linkassetuuid` always set to `NULL`.

Comment: @automatix Doctrine should take care of all this, you don't have to manually add a `@index` like you did...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. You you didn't mean, I should remove the index (and inevitably the `FOREIGN KEY`), but only the `@index` in the `Attachment` entity class annotation. Just tried this out, but the error `Column 'attachment_linkassetuuid' cannot be null` is still there.

Comment: Okay. Can you show all setters and getters that are relevant? So in `Asset` you should have `setAttachment()`, `getAttachment()` and in `Attachment` you should have `setAsset()`, `getAsset()` and please also show the `$data` you hydrate.

Comment: I've just edited the question and added the getters and setters. The data I hydrate is correct, at least the `$entityManager->persist(...)` gets a complete `Asset` entity object with a nested `Attachment`.

Comment: Updated it as well. :) It works! Thank you very much!